# Safest way in python to encrypt a password?

Tags: python, email, password-encryption

I know the best practise is to hash user passwords, and I do that for all my other web apps, but this case is a bit different.

I'm building an app that sends email notifications to a company's employees. 
The emails will be sent from the company's SMTP servers, so they'll need to give the app email/password credentials for an email account they allocate for this purpose.

Security is important to me, and I'd rather not store password that we can decrypt, but there seems like no other way to do this.
If it makes any difference, this is a multi-tenant web app.

What's the best way in python to encrypt these passwords since hashing them will do us no good in trying to authenticate with the mail server?

Thanks!

Note: The mailserver is not on the same network as the web app

Comment: Can you just set up a single email account for the service to send emails with?

Comment: Consider using OAuth.

Comment: if the smtp in on the same server, it could be set to accept local connections without requiring a password

Comment: Run a local MTA (that allows local delivery without password) on the server that your application runs, configure the company's MTA as the gateway, and make sure they configure it so that it allows relaying from the server your app is running on.

Comment: These are gonna be going to company email addresses which in my experience notoriously block things as spam. And these companies would want the emails to have their domain as the address.

Could potentially get them to set up email relay (ie. Mailgun, Sendgrid), but I'm trying to explore simpler options.

Comment: Note that this isn't run locally on the network their mailservers are on. It's a multi-tenant hosted app, and they won't necessarily be hosting the mailserver (could use Google Apps, etc.)

Comment: sorry if this is wrong, but can you use hmac for this? http://pymotw.com/2/hmac/

Comment: hmac is a one-way hash, we won't be able to get the password back to use in authenticating with the mailserver

Comment: in their SNMP they dont have ssl security???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced this issue before as well.  I think that ultimately, if you are stuck being able to produce a plain-text password inside your app, then all of the artifacts to produce the password must be accessible by the app.

I don't think there is some encryption-magic to do here.  Rely on file-system permissions to prevent anyone from accessing the data in the first place.  Notice that your SSH private key isn't encrypted in your home dir.  It is just in your home dir and you count on the fact that Linux won't let just anyone read it.

So, make a user for this app and put the passwords in a directory that only that user can access.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using **BCrypt**. There are lots of advantages to the algorithm, and most implementations handle all of these questions for you.

As described in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage):

> Bcrypt has the best kind of repute that can be achieved for a cryptographic algorithm: it has been around for quite some time, used quite widely, "attracted attention", and yet remains unbroken to date.

I've written up a detailed article about how to implement BCrypt in python as well as other frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/bcrypt